# Header flexible por debajo del contenido en Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Ojeando la [guia de diseño de Material Design](https://material.google.com/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-behavior), hay una platilla de scroll llamda `Flexible space with overlapping content` que la `ActionBar` cuando está expandida se muestra por debajo del contenido y cuando se hace scroll se colapsa.

¿Cómo se puede realizar ese overlaping del contenido?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí un [video](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_8/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsRVpzZG0zZGVNSXM/patterns-scrolling-techniques_flex_space_overlap_xhdpi_003.webm) de lo que quiero realizar

Comment: Deconocia se podía realizar esto, me parece interesante la animación para agregar a futuros proyectos. Encontré "Flexible space with overlapping content", https://material.google.com/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-behavior  y se realiza como comenta x4mp73r y Bourne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con el siguiente código:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
app:behavior_overlapTop="64dp">
```

lo importante es la linea:

```
app:behavior_overlapTop="64dp"
```

Comment: Tu solución como la de @x4mp73r me han servido. puedes tambien añadir que si se quiere poner fijo el titulo en CollapsingToolbarLayout se debe poner la propiedad app:titleEnabled="false"

Answer (score 1):

Al [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) se lo puedes agregar con `setOverLayTop` desde código:

```
NestedScrollView scrollView = (NestedScrollView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tu_nestedScrollView);

CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = 
    (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) scrollView.getLayoutParams();
AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior behavior =
    (AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior) params.getBehavior();
    behavior.setOverlayTop(128);
```